# Lumen multiple authentication types

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, lumen

I am looking for a way to authenticate the client, based on the authentication type previously set in database. So, the client is supposed to hit the url similar to this : `api.com/client/service/method`, and so based on this client field in url, I need to retrieve the authentication type set for that client in database, and try to authenticate the client using that type(For example HTTP Basic, or OAuth).

I am new to Lumen, so I was wondering if you guys have an advice on how to architect this. These requirements are set in stone, so I need to implement this the way it is described. I'm concerned with how should I organize those authentication models, and how do I even find out what type of authentication user is trying to send the request with? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply modify the authentication driver at run-time depending on the driver?

```
public function auth(array $credentials = [], $method)
{
    switch ($method) {
        case: 'oauth':
           $driver = 'oauth';              

           break;
        default:
           $driver = 'eloquent';

           break;
    }

    // Set the authentication driver.
    Config::set('auth.driver', $driver);

    // Attempt authentication.
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
         // Ex.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question. I am trying to use HTTP basic driver for authentication, but looks like when I set $driver to the value 'basic', in your example, actually EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials()  get's called? Is the HTTP Basic supported at all in Lumen ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if Lumen supports HTTP auth, I can't find anything in its documentation about it unfortunately...

Comment: I see. Then, would I able to use basic http driver if I install Laravel's auth package, https://github.com/illuminate/auth ?